# php mysqli inseting data validation

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I am working on a simple PHP code to insert data to the database, and I want to show a popup message that there are empty inputs, I tried using java script function as shown below but it didn't work, when I click insert it only shows this error: Undefined index: fname,
and it insert empty value in the database.

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x == "")
{
    alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
}}
</script>

<form name="myForm" action="test.php" method ="post"  autocomplete="off">
<div align='center'>
<div id="main">
<br>
<b>ادخل اسمك:</b> <input type="text" name="fname" value=""><br>
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])  && !empty($_POST))
{
$Name = $_POST['fname'];
$SQL = "INSERT INTO userTable (user_name) VALUES ('$Name')";

if ($conn->query($SQL) === TRUE) {

header("Location: test2.php"); /* Redirect browser */
exit();
} else {

echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
 'validateForm();',
 '</script>';
} 
$conn->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: You did not close your `<form>`, you try to redirect when you already have an output. You don't check if `$_POST['fname']` is set. Maybe you should debug your code step-by-step.

Comment: most important : you are wide open to SQL injections : you **MUST NOT** use raw user input in your sql queries. have a look at prepared statements

Comment: I closed the form in the above code but still the same error,

Comment: you are mixing php code and js code. your validate function is a js script and you try to execute this function from php. this won't work. You have to do the validation in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you use your `validateForm()` function? I suppose you use it in a submit button with `onclick` method, or something like this. But your `return false` doesn't work in function because form still send all the data. You should add **return** in method like this:

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="test.php" method ="post"  autocomplete="off">
```

So your form will get `return false` from function validateForm and will stop sending a form.